# Tableau - Fixed calculated field depending on date filter

Tags: filter, data-science, tableau-api, data-analysis, business-intelligence

I'm new to Tableau. I am trying to make an inventory report which tells the user how much of certain product he/she should buy in advance.

Depending on the amount of days selected on the filter, the difference in days of the complete period should be calculated. For example: If the filtered dates are from 1/03/2021 to 09/03/2021, the result should be equal to 9. The formula I used is the following: `date_difference = DATEDIFF("day",MIN(DATE([Fecha])), MAX(DATE([Fecha]))) + 1`

[image]

The problem comes when I try to use the value given by such date filter. My next calculation should be:
`calc = Quantity Inventory / (Units sold / date_difference)`. Both Quantity Inventory and Units sold are calculated fields in which I have no problem. However, instead of having a fixed value of 9, date_difference changes as shown in the image, giving me incorrect results for the desired calculation.

[image]

How can I make sure that the calculated field date_difference has the value of 9 on all rows?. Actually, if I add date_difference field by itself in a different Page it does show the proper value. The problem occurs when calculating *calc* and trying to add it to the table.

*Note: Remember that the value of date_difference will change, depending on the range of time selected on the date filter*

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1** Use this calculation for `date_difference` instead

```
DATEDIFF('day', {min(DATE([Fecha]))}, {max(DATE([Fecha]))}) +1
```

**Step-2** Add `Fecha` filter to context, by right clicking it in filters shelf.

This will solve your problem.  See the GIF

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @AnilGoyal your solution works great. Just for sake of knowledge, what does adding the Filter to Context actually do? Thanks again.

Comment: Adding the filter to context changes it's order of [precedence](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/order_of_operations.htm#:~:text=In%20the%20order%20of%20operations%2C%20a%20dimension%20filter%20is%20applied,instead%20of%20the%20table%20calculation.)